# n == 7 giving me an indentation error

Tags: python

```
# Rate Our Love !! 

def love(n):
    if n < 0 : 
        print "Why would it be negative?!" 
    elif n == 0 : 
        print "well that is just hurtful" 
    elif n == 1 :
        print "I REALLY love you" 
    elif n == 2 : 
        print "You make me smile at least once, each and every day"
    elif n == 3 : 
        print"you wouldn't believe how annoying it was to get this program to run properly! but it was worth it"
    elif n == 4 : 
        print "let's " + "shoot a little higher than that"
    elif n == 5 : 
        print "you're unforgettable, that's what you are" 
    elif n == 6 :
        print "always have, always '____' *hint* fill in the blank " 
    elif n == 7 :
        print "i could never leave you, I love you too much" 
    elif n == 8 : 
        print "an 8/10 is still only a B, maybe I'm not trying hard enough" 
    elif n == 9 : 
        print " well, I'm not perfect yet, could have seen that one coming. Guess I just have to keep trying :)" 
    elif n == 10 : 
        print " i think you're exaggerating, i really am not that good yet"     
    else:
        print "I still really hope that we could get married someday."
```

why do i keep getting an indentation error for n== 7 if its formatted just like the rest of this definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try running with `python -t`

That will warn you if you're mixing spaces and tabs making it appear like you have the same indentation level when in reality you probably don't.

From the man page:

> **-t**
>   Issue a warning when a source file mixes tabs and spaces for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces.  Issue an  error  when
>                 the option is given twice.

Comment: Hitting `edit` on the posting, this appears to be correct: the line for `n==7` uses spaces, the rest of the code uses tabs.

Comment: @Moshe -- I didn't bother checking that.  I just couldn't see any other reason OP could possibly have this error.

Comment: the tab suggestion worked!